# How to delete a dune dashboard I created?

Tags: dune

How to delete a dune dashboard I created? cannot find any solution or docs on this.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can only `archive` dashboards.
To do that on the web interface...

1. go to your dashboard
2. Click on `Settings` on the top right (a popup should open)
3. Click on the bottom right `archive`

[image]